# Tax filing requirement for Teens 16 to 21 years

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, children

in 2021 a kid( approx age 16) had some income (less than 1.5K) for working part time and needed to file tax return. in 2022 if that kid does not earn any money, will he still need to file tax return for 2022 , meaning once the filing starts it never ends ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the filing requirement is not dependent on whether or not you filed the year before.

If you aren’t sure whether or not you need to file in a given situation, the filing requirement criteria are located in the [Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1040) instructions in a section called [“Do you have to file?”](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#en_US_2021_publink24811vd0e622). There are three charts there:

- Chart A is used for most people.
- Chart B is for children or anyone who is considered a dependent of someone else.
- Chart C list some special circumstances that make you have to file even if you don’t meet the requirements of Charts A or B.

In your kid’s situation, Chart B would probably apply, and if he had no income, he would not have to file a tax return.

Comment: To be clear, B is used for dependents (as defined for tax), whether children or not. Children are _often_ dependents but not always, and the Q doesn't give info to determine; B doesn't automatically apply solely because the person is a child. Plus, if this child was dependent in 2021 with 1.5k _earned_ income (and assuming no other income) they _weren't_ required to file as claimed.